# How can you update a field that is locked by system via Plugin?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have a field in my contract line entity that is locked by the system as shown here:

[image]

I want to update this field using a plugin via the following code:

```c#
//Update Contract Line StartDate
                    Entity updatedContractLine = new Entity("contractdetail")
                    {
                        Id = entity.Id
                    };

                    updatedContractLine["activeon"] = startDate;
                    service.Update(updatedContractLine);
```

Would this work? If not, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Field behavior - Field is read-only**:

This helps to render the form control in disabled mode. Just related to user experience.

**Locking - Lock the field on the form:**

This just locks the attribute in the form editor from being removed from the form by Developer/Customizer. Just related to design mode.

[Red & Black padlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50878836/7920473)

In a nutshell, those properties has nothing to do with sdk update. You can update any attribute including `activeon` which is not marked as read-only by SDK. For Ex. CreatedOn, allotmentsoverage, etc are Read-only properties. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/contractdetail?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#properties)